# Building APK with Visual Studio gives me invalid resource directory name. Why?

Tags: android, cordova, build

When building my Cordova solution in Visual Studio, it gives me the following error:

```
\platforms\android\res\drawable-landhdpi: Error: Invalid resource directory name.
```

I don't think I've changed anything regarding these resources. Below you can find the content of the aforementioned directory:

**..\platforms\android\res:**

[image]

This is on Cordova CLI: 6.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think that's the problem, if you have a directory named "drawable-landhdpi" it should be changed to "drawable-land-hdpi". This is the correct format.

Comment: During build Visual Studio is creating the "platform" folder automatically with this folders in specific android/res . Any idea how I can control this ?